# How can I position the stciker options?

Tags: android, position

Using the code below, I wanted to get a result like in the picture, the code works when the angle is 0 but if it isn't 0, it doesn't work correctly.

I want to do: [click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnKN0.jpg)

```
 if (showIcons) {
    float rotation = calculateRotation(x4, y4, x3, y3);
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.size(); i++) {
      BitmapStickerIcon icon = icons.get(i);
      switch (icon.getPosition()) {
        case BitmapStickerIcon.LEFT_TOP:

          configIconMatrix(icon, x1 - 15, y1 + 15, rotation);
          break;

        case BitmapStickerIcon.RIGHT_TOP:
          configIconMatrix(icon, x2 + 15, y2 + 15, rotation);
          break;

        case BitmapStickerIcon.LEFT_BOTTOM:
          configIconMatrix(icon, x3 - 15, y3 - 15, rotation);
          break;

        case BitmapStickerIcon.RIGHT_BOTOM:
          configIconMatrix(icon, x4 + 15, y4 - 15, rotation);
          break;
      }
      icon.draw(canvas, borderPaint);
    }
```

Comment: use canvas.rotate()

Comment: Other sticker do not rotate when canvas rotates?

Comment: use canvas.save()....canvas.restore()